# Refreshing AWS session token with Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm having some difficulties refreshing my temporary session token using AWS with node.js.

I'm retrieving my security credentials and requiring my routes like this

```
  function start() {

    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var AWSSecurityCredentials = require('./aws/securityCredentials.js');
    AWSSecurityCredentials.get(function(credentials) {

      AWS.config.accessKeyId = credentials.accessKeyId;
      AWS.config.secretAccessKey = credentials.secretAccessKey;
      AWS.config.sessionToken = credentials.token;

      require('./routes/mobile.js')(app, AWS);
    })

  }
```

and inside `mobile.js` I'm initializing the objects being used, like S3:

```
    var routes = function(app, AWS) {

      var s3 = new AWS.S3({signatureVersion: 'v4',
        region: config.aws.s3.region,
        apiVersion: config.aws.s3.apiVersion
      });
   }
   module.exports = routes;
```

I have a loop checking periodically when the current credentials have expired, and then I fire `start()` again. I thought this would be enough to refresh the AWS object and that it would be passed on to the routes, but it does not. I also tried clearing the cache of the objects before firing `start()` again, but it did not help either:

```
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('aws-sdk')]
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./aws/securityCredentials.js')]
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./routes/mobile.js')]
```

Right now I'm a bit clueless as to how I'm going to make this work, I can't restart the server every 5 or 6 hours in production just to load the new AWS session token.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the explicit `AWSSecurityCredentials`?  I thought the SDK handled this automatically.  If I'm right (and I very well may be entirely wrong) then you're disabling the automatic refresh by setting static credentials.

Comment: Not sure about how your `AWSSecurityCredentials.get()` implementation works but it least, it should attempt to refresh credentials if they are not yet loaded or have expired. Also, it should be called just before the AWS service call to avoid your "loop-then-start()" approach and make sure credentials are valid. Or, you could just use [AWS.Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html), which already has a `get()` method that gets the existing credentials and refreshes them if they have expired.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot right on, I was disabling by doing it this way. Thank you:)